# IE 11 polyfill-eventsource added missing EventSource to window

Tags: nuxt.js, internet-explorer-11, babel-polyfill

I'm from South Korea and Internet Explorer share is very high there.

While constructing a website using Nuxt, IE suddenly started to get an [object error]. But I don't know exactly what caused this problem.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

this is my `nuxt.config.js`

---

```js
import config from './configs'

const { gaId } = config.analytics

export default {
  loading: '~/components/common/CommonLoadingComponent.vue',

  // Global page headers (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head)
  head: {
    title: 'FKIE!!',
    meta: [
      {
        charset: 'utf-8',
      },
      {
        name: 'viewport',
        content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1',
      },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: '',
      },
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href:
          'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+KR:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap',
      },
      ...config.icons.map((href) => ({ rel: 'stylesheet', href })),
    ],
    script: [
      { src: '/js/babel-polyfill/7.12.1/polyfill.min.js' },
      {
        src: '/js/IE.js',
        body: true,
        defer: true,
      },
    ],
  },

  // Global CSS (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css)
  css: ['~/assets/scss/theme.scss'],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins)
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/axios.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/v-calendar.js', mode: 'client', ssr: false },
    { src: '~/plugins/animate.js', mode: 'client' },
    // { src: '~/plugins/apexcharts.js', mode: 'client' },
    // { src: '~/plugins/clipboard.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-shortkey.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/ckeditor4.js', mode: 'client' },

    { src: '~/filters/capitalize.js' },
    { src: '~/filters/lowercase.js' },
    { src: '~/filters/uppercase.js' },
    { src: '~/filters/formatCurrency.js' },
    { src: '~/filters/formatDate.js' },
  ],

  // Auto import components (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components)
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended) (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/moment',
    '@nuxtjs/svg',
    [
      '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
      {
        customVariables: ['~/assets/scss/vuetify/variables/_index.scss'],
        optionsPath: '~/configs/vuetify.js',
        treeShake: true,
        customProperties: true,
        defaultAssets: {
          font: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  // Modules (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/google-gtag',
    'nuxt-clipboard',
  ],

  'google-gtag': {
    id: gaId,
    debug: false, // enable to track in dev mode
    disableAutoPageTrack: false, // disable if you don't want to track each page route with router.afterEach(...).
  },

  // Axios module configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios)
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
  },

  // Axios Proxy Configuration
  proxy: {
    '/api/': {
      target: 'http://localhost:7777/api',
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api/': '',
      },
    },
    changeOrigin: true,
  },

  // Vuetify options
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    treeShake: true,
  },

  // moment options
  moment: {
    defaultTimezone: 'Asia/Seoul',
  },

  clipboard: {
    autoSetContainer: true,
  },

  // Build Configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build)
  build: {
    transpile: [
      'v-calendar/lib/components/date-picker.umd',
      '~/plugins/animate.js',
      '~/plugins/apexcharts.js',
      '~/plugins/clipboard.js',
      '~/plugins/vue-shortkey.js',
      'is-https',
    ],
    vendor: ['babel-polyfill'],
    babel: {
      compact: true,
      presets: [
        [
          'vue-app',
          {
            useBuiltIns: true,
            targets: { ie: 11, uglify: true },
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
    parallel: true,
    html: {
      minify: {
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        decodeEntities: true,
        minifyCSS: false,
        minifyJS: false,
        processConditionalComments: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        trimCustomFragments: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
      },
    },
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    ADMIN_NET_URL: process.env.ADMIN_NET_URL,
    XML_SERVER_URL: process.env.XML_SERVER_URL,
    MARKET_SERVER_URL: process.env.MARKET_SERVER_URL,
  },
}
```

---

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "admin-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt --dotenv .env.development --port 7888",
    "build:stage": "nuxt build --dotenv .env.stage",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start:stage": "nuxt start --dotenv .env.stage",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/google-gtag": "^1.0.4",
    "@nuxtjs/moment": "^1.6.1",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy": "^2.1.0",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.0",
    "ckeditor4-vue": "^1.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.14.0",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.4.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.6",
    "nuxt-clipboard": "0.0.4",
    "v-calendar": "^2.3.0",
    "vue-shortkey": "^3.1.7",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.24.3",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.6",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^3.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^2.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/svg": "^0.1.12",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults",
    "> 1%",
    "IE 11"
  ]
}
```

After running Npm Run Dev, clicking on a page in the page list causes the above error. I don't know which one is the problem

Comment: What if you expand on the error? We need to find out where this is coming from. Maybe `i18n`? Also, what are the changes that you pulled? Faster to check the updates in your `package.json` directly. Lastly, IE11 is already deprecated and will be totally done in less than a year, not sure if it's worth the trouble at this point: https://death-to-ie11.com/

Comment: Maybe try to downgrade axios' version as suggested here: https://www.programmersought.com/article/31274038409/

Comment: @kissu first of all thank you For correcting my questions and correcting my spelling and comment too ^_^.

Comment: @kissu We also know that IE11 is disappearing, but Korea cannot afford to have a very high share of IE. Korean developers are well aware that this is a very sad thing and are outraged.

Comment: @kissu Thank you for commenting. I'll try to catch a bug by referring to the link you gave me. I'm sure you're a good person. ^^b

Comment: You say it worked until you pulled from remote branch, could you please explain more about this? Does it mean the website doesn't work with some local file but works with some remote server resources? If so, I think you can clear browser cache and try again.

Comment: @YuZhou Forget Pull. i think it is some confusion . sorry  1. look at the my pacakge.json 2. check my nuxt.config.js  After running Npm Run Dev, clicking on a page in the page list causes the above error.  I don't know which one is the problem.

Comment: Which line of code does the error occur? I can't locate the issue with only the package and config file. It could be better that you can provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**. You can use some online code editor like [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) to show your code snippet.

Comment: @YuZhou Thank you for your continued help. My team decided to deal with this problem together. I think it will be resolved soon. I don't know what code caused this problem. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: That's great. You can also post the solution here if you solve the issue.